# Kill process based on its commandline arguments in Python?

Tags: python, windows

I have many instances of a process running, but only want to kill the instance that has specific commandline arguments. In other words, killing `processname arg1 arg2 arg3` isntead of just `processname`.

Comment: Is this process `processname` something you are writing or something already written by someone else? Is there anything distinctive in each process based on its command line arguments, such as in the window title? What have you tried so far and why is it not working?

Comment: FWIW, you can get that information using the WMI [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372) class. In Python you can use Tim Golden's [wmi module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html). For example, `c = wmi.WMI();` `procs = c.Win32_Process(Name='processname');` `for p in procs: print(p.CommandLine)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `taskkill.exe` doesn't include a filter to target a specific instance of a process based on its arguments (eg `taskkill /f /im notepad /fi "args contains 'd:\foo.txt'"`) 